# SAP GUI opens Excel Automatically after Report Extraction

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I'm trying to automate SAP GUI with VBA to extract some reports from Transactions (FBL5N-FBL3N).

There are two main problems:

1- Once SAP GUI Extraction is done it automatically opens the Excel sheet for this extraction

2- Excel Gives an error in the end of the loop but it extracts everything successfully (run error ..619 )

I want to Code the VBA as it extracts everything without opening the excel sheet and gives a MsgBox says "Done" once the extraction is done or once it encounters a blank Cell.

The code below is what I've done so far.

```
Public Sub fbl3n()


'setting the connection with sap:
Dim App, Connection, session As Object
Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set App = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set Connection = App.Children(0)
Set session = Connection.Children(0)



'Fbl3n
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim Z As Long
lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For Z = 1 To lastrow

session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = Cells(Z + 1, 4).Value
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 17
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtV-LOW").Text = Cells(Z + 1, 1).Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtV-LOW").caretPosition = 6
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[8]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtPA_STIDA").Text = Cells(Z + 1, 2).Value
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtPA_STIDA").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtPA_STIDA").caretPosition = 10
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[0]/menu[3]/menu[1]").Select
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = Cells(Z + 1, 3).Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").caretPosition = 22
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press

Call excel



Next


If Not session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]", False) Is Nothing Then

session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press

End If

MsgBox ("Done")

End Sub

Public Sub clear()


Range("A2:D10000").Select
    Selection.ClearContents

End Sub

Public Sub excel()

Dim xlApp As Object

Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)

myPath = Cells(1, "K").Value
myFileName = Cells(Z + 1, 3).Value

Set xlApp = GetObject(myPath & myFileName).Application

xlApp.Workbooks(1).Close False

xlApp.Quit



End Sub
```

Comment: You should write parameter on your excel() sub, else it make no sense for keep calling the sub in your looping.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more ?

Comment: Such as sub `excel(zRow)`, so that you can pass value when you call `excel(Z)` .

Comment: The Function that i'm using seems to be wrong. It closes all excel windows and even the macro workbook.

Comment: Ya, it is hard to tell what is main issue, especially VBA with Gui Scripting need do many testing until it work well. Great you have to opportunity to use as my current company disable the function all, haha.